# Filtering LEFT JOIN results

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables: authorizations and settlements.  'Settlements' contains a forign key reference to authorizations.

A settlement can also have a status (ERROR, ACCEPTED, etc).

Given this data:

```
Authorizations           Settlements
id                id   |   auth_id   | status
-----             ---------------------------
1                  1         1          ERROR
2                  2         1          ACCEPTED
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find all authorizations that don't have an ACCEPTED settlement record.  I've tried a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but it returns too many rows.  For example:

`SELECT * FROM authorizations a

LEFT OUTER JOIN settlements s ON a.id = s.auth_id

WHERE s.status is null OR s.status != 'ACCEPTED'`

The problem with this is that it will still return an authorization record if it has more than one settlement record, and one of those is ACCEPTED.  Or, if there is more than one ERROR record, the authorization will be returned twice.

How can I only fetch *single* authorization records that don't have a corresponding settlement record with a status of "ACCEPTED"?  Is it possible with straight SQL, or will I have to filter the results in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    authorizations a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    Settlements s
        WHERE   s.auth_id = a.id
                AND s.status = 'ACCEPTED'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT a.* FROM authorizations a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT S.* from settlements s1 
WHERE  s1.status = 'ACCEPTED')
ON a.id = s.auth_id
WHERE s.auth_id is null
```

This picks out all the records which are accepted and then takes the authorizations which are not inthat group.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, checking for the s.status being null is unnecessary if you change the JOIN to be a RIGHT join.

Will work with SQL Server 2005+ or Oracle 9i+:

```
WITH unacceptedSettlements AS (
     SELECT s.auth_id
       FROM SETTLEMENTS s
      WHERE s.status != 'ACCEPTED'
   GROUP BY s.auth_id)
SELECT t.*
  FROM AUTHORIZATIONS t
  JOIN unacceptedSettlements us ON us.auth_id = t.auth_id
```

Any database alternative:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM AUTHORIZATIONS t
  JOIN (SELECT s.auth_id 
         FROM SETTLEMENTS s
         WHERE s.status != 'ACCEPTED'
      GROUP BY s.auth_id) us ON us.auth_id = t.auth_id
```

Comment: Both your solutions will not return an `authorization`  if there is no corresponding record in `settlements`. In the `@op`'s example, authorization `2` will not be returned.

Comment: Per the OP: "How can I only fetch single authorization records that don't have a corresponding settlement record with a status of "ACCEPTED"?"  There's no requirement stated for needing AUTHORIZATION records without any SETTLEMENT records.

Comment: Authorization `2` doesn't have a corresponding settlement record with a status of `ACCEPTED`. That was the whole point of the `LEFT JOIN` in the original query.

Comment: Then why does the supplied query contain "status != 'ACCEPTED'"?

Comment: Yes, I had that in my SQL because I was writing the query incorrectly.  I do want to get back an auth record if there are zero corresponding settlements.

Comment: And your answer employs the same logic.